# Time Limits on Filing Closed EPO application in United States?

Tags: patent-applications, uspto, epo

A previous application for an European Patent Grant was "closed" by the European Patent Office. What is the time limit the same application can be filed with US Patent Office?

Comment: As asked, the question is very vague. When was the EPO filed, closed? Is the same inventor looking to file in the US?

Comment: The original application was filed with EPO on February 14, 2010. EPO misunderstood claims and everyrhing and eventually refused the app by closing the files. Whose IP is this filed application. The applicant wants to file the sama application as an original new application with the amended claims already filed with EPO, which are, as EPO says patentable, as new and innovative, but not compatible with the original application filed with them

Answer (score 1):

According to MPEP 213 and 35 U.S.C. 119

**Benefit of earlier filing date; right of priority.**

> (a) An application for patent for an invention filed in this country
>   by any person who has, or whose legal representatives or assigns have, previously
>   regularly filed an application .......................... if the application in this country is filed within **twelve months** from the
>   earliest date on which such foreign application was filed.

In your case if twelve month have expired you will not to able to file application in US. In case you have filed PCT application time limit exceeds to 30 month from priority date.